# Cannot insert into hasura when it uses UUID as ID

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, hasura

I'm trying to use react admin with ra-hasura data provider, when I try to create a record where the id is a UUID which is actually auto generated by postgresql, the interface of react admin insert a UUID generated by the react admin itself as an id and fails to create the record at the end in the database.

I was doing the same without inserting the id in another application "not react admin" and it was successful, what I need to do to prevent the app from doing this behavior, is this because there should be always and id in the request ? and how to overcome this ?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

Sorry it appeared that the record is being created in the database but with no referenced user id , and for that I was not able to see it under the user I'm using.

Conclusion is that react admin actually returned back the id and make it appears dynamically in the interface indicating the record is actually created